# Orleans performance issue with GetGrain and saving to Event Store

Tags: orleans

I'm using Orelans (`2.0.3`) with `SQL` database (2017). Database is on the same host where application is located. Currently I'm struggling with performance issue for :

```
var purchaseGrain = _grainFactory.GetGrain<IPurchaseGrain>(id);
await purchaseGrain.Create(id, command);
```

Create method for test purposes do nothing and looks like :

```
public Task Create(Guid id, CreatePurchaseCommand message)
        {
            var @event = new PurchaseCreatedEvent
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = message.Name,
                Type = message.Type
            };

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Time execution of this part takes a long time :

```
var purchaseGrain = _grainFactory.GetGrain<IPurchaseGrain>(id);
await purchaseGrain.Create(id, command);
```

Example time execution in miliseconds:

```
79
105
145
69
90
108
140
74
97
128
153
79
103
140
67
95
130
158
87
119
152
75
102
134
```

I have also problem with the following part :

```
protected async Task Publish(IEvent @event)
        {
            RaiseEvent(@event); //Rise event works very fast
            await ConfirmEvents(); // here is long time execution issue
        }
```

Example execution time in miliseconds for ConfirmEvents :

```
172
205
165
231
294
222
259
208
177
274
238
228
200
```

Everything is working on my local machine with CPU intel core i7, 16 GB of RAM.
Please let me know, which configuration should I provide to find the reason of this long time execution.
Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

Without directly addressing the performance issues, some background.

Even your `Create()` method does nothing, Orleans needs to administer a lot of stuff upon the first call: have to locate/create this grain in the grain directory, etc. and this requires some communication and DB access, ie. this is not a few CPU cycle dummy call.

On the event-sourcing side: `RaiseEvent()` is a cheap call, it stores the event in a queue in the local memory (in some future version this will be renamed to `EnqueueEvent()` to be clear what happens), and when the grain goes idle (or at least waits in an `await`) or when you call `ConfirmEvents()` will Orleans store the events. And storing events also requires some administration, eg. it guarantees strong (linearizable) consistency even if there are multiple instances across clusters.

Without addressing your 100-200ms execution times please note, these algos are designed for 10s, 100s or 1000s of machines, and not optimized for a single machine development environment. And even in live environment, not a single grain call will be fast, but the general throughput (multiple grains and multiple calls distributed across a real cluster) will be high (16.000 req/s/silo (25 x A4 (8core 14GB), 2hop/req, 200kreq/s/cluster, 2*200k/25=16k)).

I way too unqualified to say anything more about Orleans performance. If you have a sample project showing you performance issues, upload it to github, raise an issue, if it takes only a few minutes of the developers to analyse your issue, they will help, but they need at least detailed logs to see what is the real issue.